# Function calling numerous other functions

Tags: vba, excel

I need to log into a website and do numerous things such as updates or scrape data. But rather than having a few login code, I would like to sum all into one and use it to access the other situation based on the information given. Example, I have a login code which calls:

```
 Public Function LoginPhase(FunctionKey, KeyX)
 ...
 codes
 ...

 Call FunctionKey(KeyX)
 DoEvents

 ...
 End Function
```

and have a button which calls:

```
Sub UpdateAcc_Click()

Call LoginPhase(UpdateFunction, 132)

End Sub
```

and another button which calls:

```
Sub UpdateAcc_Click()

Call LoginPhase(DataFunction, 132)

End Sub
```

and of course there's function codes which is called `UpdateFunction` and `DataFunction`.

How do I get it to function the way I intend to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Public Function LoginPhase(FunctionKey, KeyX)

Select Case FunctionKey
    Case "UpdateFunction"
        UpdateFunction KeyX
    Case "DataFunction"
        DataFunction KeyX
    Case Else
        MsgBox "FunctionKey """ & FunctionKey & """ is unknown"
End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define all your functions in a class module (ie. ThisWorkbook), you can use CallByName to invoke them as shown [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/186143) (the link is about VB6,  but it's the same with vba).

```
Public Function LoginPhase(FunctionKey, KeyX)
 ...
 codes
 ...

 CallByName ThisWorkbook, FunctionKey, vbMethod, KeyX
 DoEvents

 ...
 End Function
```